# Atualizar valores em uma matriz mantendo os elementos jà modificados anteriormente

Tags: java, array

Eu estou criando um game board, utilizando uma matriz de 2d array. Durante o jogo os jogadores acertam ou erram e isso tem que ficar impresso no board.
Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso atualizar a matriz sem perder e que foi impresso anteriormente.

Minha primeira matriz:

```
public void drawBoard() {   
        int[] m = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
        int[] n = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
        int position = 1;

        System.out.println("\n" + "This is your board : " + "\n" + "        '**' means hited and '~~' means missed" + "\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < height+1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width+1; j++) {
                board[i][0] = String.valueOf(m[i]);
                board[0][j] = String.valueOf(n[j]);
                board[i+1][j+1] = String.valueOf(position);//"&";
                position++;
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
                this.ship[i][j] = board[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

As interacões dos jogadores:

```
public void guess() {
        System.out.println("\n" + "Please, enter a row number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n" + "Please, enter a col number: ");
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        col = input2.nextInt();
        boolean win = false;
        String [] z = {"**","~~"};
        int linha = 0;
        int coluna = 0;

        if (ship[row][col].equals("A")) {
            hit++;
            linha = row;
            coluna = col;
            ship[row][col] = "**";
            //board[row][col] = "**";
            pickedShip[linha*coluna] = ship[row][col];
            guess[lin][colu] = pickedShip[linha*coluna];
            System.out.println("Hey! You hit it!");
            //HitBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
        else if (ship[row][col].equals("B")) {
            hit++;
            ship[row][col] = "**";
            //board[row][col] = "**";
            pickedShip[row*col] = ship[row][col];
            System.out.println("Hey! You hit it!");
            //HitBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
        else if (ship[row][col].equals("C")) {
            hit++;
            ship[row][col] = "**";
            //board[row][col] = "**";
            pickedShip[row*col] = ship[row][col];
            //pickedShip[(row+2)*(col+2)] = ship[row][col];
            System.out.println("Hey! You hit it!");
            //HitBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
        else if (ship[row][col].equals("D")) {
            hit++;
            ship[row][col] = "**";
            //board[row][col] = "**";
            pickedShip[row*col] = ship[row][col];
            System.out.println("Hey! You hit it!");
            //HitBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
        else if (ship[row][col].equals("E")) {
            hit++;
            ship[row][col] = "**";
            //board[row][col] = "**";
            pickedShip[row*col] = ship[row][col];
            System.out.println("Hey! You hit it!");
            //HitBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
        else if (ship[row][col].equals("F")) {
            hit++;
            ship[row][col] = "**";
            //board[row][col] = "**";
            pickedShip[row*col] = ship[row][col];
            System.out.println("Hey! You hit it!");
            //HitBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
        else if(ship[row][col].equals("**") || ship[row][col].equals("~~")){
            System.out.println("Sorry! It was already picked!");
        }
        else {
            //miss++;
            ship[row][col] = "~~";
            //board[row][col] = "~~";
            pickedShip[row*col] = ship[row][col];
            System.out.println("\n" + "Sorry, you miss it!" + "\n");
            //missedBoard();
            NewBoard();
        }
    }
```

E finalmente minha nova matrix:

```
public void NewBoard() {
        int[] m = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
        int[] n = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

        for(int i = 0; i < height+1; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < width+1; j++) {
                board[i][0] = String.valueOf(m[i]);
                board[0][j] = String.valueOf(n[j]);
                board[i+1][j+1] = "&";
                board[lin][colu] = guess[lin][colu];
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t"); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O que poderia ser feito é guardar os valores em uma string, eu aconselho utilizar o StringBuilder pois ele é o indicado para concatenação de valores em um laço de repetição, algo como o que segue abaixo:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < height+1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width+1; j++) {
            board[i][0] = String.valueOf(m[i]);
            board[0][j] = String.valueOf(n[j]);
            board[i+1][j+1] = String.valueOf(position);//"&";
            position++;
            guardadorDeValores.append(board[i][j]).append("\t");
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
            this.ship[i][j] = board[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println();
        guardadorDeValores.append("/n");
    }
```

Essa variável guardador de valores pode ser recebida no construtor da sua classe como dependência.